# How do you decode SAS "Sense" or "CDB" data reported by an HBA or RAID controller?

Tags: raid, hardware-raid, sas, broadcom, megaraid

My Broadcom-based RAID adapter (Cisco UCSC-RAID-M5HD) reported the following "Unexpected sense" error:

```
Unexpected sense:   PD  #012    =   Port 0 - 7:1:9No addtional sense information,   CDB  
=    0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00    ,   Sense   =    0x72 0x02 0x04 0x11 0x00 0x00 0x00
0x34 0x00 0x0a 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x0a 0x00 0x00 0x00
0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x02 0x06 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x03 0x02 0x00
0x00 0x05 0x02 0x00 0x00 0x80 0x02 0xf5 0x53 0x81 0x06 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
```

It is a hot spare SAS drive that was spinning up from power-off (probably for a patrol read). It gives this sense code during a power state transition when spinning up. I have always assumed that it is just not ready to accept commands yet, but I would really like to know what it actually means:

**How do you decode SAS sense / CDB data?**